# JPA NamedNativeQuery with SqlResultMapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have a problem with native query. I have following entity:

```
    @Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name =  ExampleEntity.Q.getTestQuery, query = "SELECT a.name as name FROM ExampleEntity a WHERE a.id = 5", resultSetMapping = "nameMapping")
})

@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "nameMapping",
    entities = @EntityResult(
        entityClass = ExampleEntity.class,
        fields = {
            @FieldResult(name="name", column="name")
        }))


@Table(name = "ExampleEntity")
public class ExampleEntity implements Serializable {

    public static class Q {
        public static final String getTestQuery = "getTestQuery";
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
```

and I am trying to call this query in my @Service with following code:

```
Query qz = em.createNativeQuery(ExampleEntity.Q.getTestQuery, "nameMapping");
qz.getResultList();
```

it returns error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

It is only simple example, but shows my problem.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, add the full stack trace.

Comment: Exception in service.test() with cause = 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet' and exception = 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet'

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `createNativeQuery` method expects SQL query string as the first parameter rather than the name used to refer to the SQL query itself. Here is the method definition:

> public Query createNativeQuery(**String sqlString**, String
>   resultSetMapping);

which brings us to the following:

```
Query qz = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT a.id, a.name FROM ExampleEntity a WHERE a.id = 5", 
                                "nameMapping");
```

---

The preferred solution is to use `createNamedQuery` instead which expects the name of the SQL query defined in a metadata:

> public Query createNamedQuery(**String name**);

so based on the above we can fix the exception with the following:

```
Query qz = em.createNamedQuery(ExampleEntity.Q.getTestQuery);
```

Comment: I was trying solve issue this way, but i received:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id1_7_0_ was not found in this ResultSet.
but I have not colummn like this...

Comment: The PSQL exception is related to id column. Add `@FieldResult(name="id", column="id")` to the fields mapping and update the query e.g. `SELECT a.id, a.name FROM ExampleEntity a WHERE a.id = 5`